# How to successfully use a BOOL in Xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, boolean, avfoundation

I just finished Stanford's iPhone lesson that uses AVFoundation.  It was the class where the TA had us make an App that displayed video and then put sunglasses on the face with face recognition.  So I wanted to hook up a couple of switches and sliders to do different things.  The first was a slider that changed the value of the hue filter.  Then I wanted to make a switch to show the sunglasses or not.  But the switch does not turn the sunglasses off.  Although the switch works.  I declared a BOOL in the properties with

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL sunGlasses;
```

I synthesized it and then hooked the switch up to the following action

```
- (IBAction)toggleGlasses:(id)sender 
{
if (_mySwitch.on)
{
    NSLog(@"toggle is on");
    self.sunGlasses = YES;
}else {
    NSLog(@"toggle is off");
    self.sunGlasses = NO;
}
}
```

Then under the method for -(void) captureOutput, that is where the hue gets changed and the face recognition is I added to the face recognition portion

```
if ((faceFound) && (self.sunGlasses = YES)){
    [self.glasses setHidden:NO];
}else{
    [self.glasses setHidden:YES];
}
```

It used to be just if (faceFound) and then hid the glasses or showed them.  However, this does not make the glasses go away if you switch the switch to off.

Comment: In addition to checking for equality by assigning (you used = instead of ==), you should not check BOOL values against YES.  It's not a true boolean type, and can have lots of different values (256, in fact).  You would do better by writing that statement as "if (faceFound && self.sunFlasses) {"

Comment: @Jody Hagins,  thanks for the quick reply.  Did you mean to put a bracket after the closing parenthesis?  Should I check the bool against zero and one instead os true and false?  Thanks again.

Comment: I include the curly-bracket just because that was the line I was indicating to replace, and it was in the original line.  No, do not check bools agains any explicit value.  Any non-zero value will be "true" and 0 will be "false."  Unfortunately, there is a lot of code (including apple sample code) that explicitly checks against YES and NO.  NO is not so bad, because false is only 0.

Comment: @JodyHagins, Thanks so much for your help.  I figured it out.  See below.  Thanks again!!

Comment: You don't even need the BOOL property, just use the one of the switch.You only need to replace the explicit YES/NO you used (not the code you posted) with `[self.glasses setHidden:!_mySwitch.on];`

Comment: @Moxy, thanks for the input.  It makes sense what you said.  Thanks for showing me another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used:

```
self.sunGlasses = YES
```

The single = is an assignment. It sets the value of that property, and when this statement is used within a larger expression it's value is YES. So the "if" condition is always true and the branch that shows sunglasses is always taken.

Use the double equals == to test for equality.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Do I still leave the self.?  Because I then got a warning that said "equality comparison result unused". I also changed the = to a == in the face found section.  Any ideas about that?  Thanks so much for taking the time to help out a newbie!

Comment: I figured it out.  I used your == advice and Jody's if advice and it all worked as planned.  I have a lot to learn, but thanks to the people on this site, I am starting to make some headway!!!  Thanks again.

Comment: please see above, I forgot to put your name on it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use

if(self.sunGlasses){

}

to validate the

Comment: Can you fix your code formatting and finish your sentence please?